# Show only comment textarea, if entered something show required fields for anonymous user

Tags: 7, comments

I [want](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158893/how-to-motivate-visitors-to-comment-technically) to make commenting easy for anonymous users. ***"Anonymous posters must leave their contact information."*** is enabled.

### What I want to do is to show **only** the comment text field **at first** and if the user **enter** some text (more than 20 characters etc) then show the other fields (name, e-mail, homepage).

I think it will be better not to show 3-4 empty fields instead of one text area to comment. First, **focus** on the comment (content) and then the required fields.

[image: Commenting should be easier!]

**Is there any out of the box solution for this or if anybody did that before?**

Comment: You can do it with jQuery. Or do you want to use form ajax?

Comment: @MrD; yes, it can be done with jQuery.

Comment: so what do you want in your question?

Comment: **"Is there any out of the box solution for this or if anybody did that before?"** And only knowing it can be done with jQuery isn't enough.

Comment: @herci, it isnt our job to do the research for you - if you ask a vague question, expect a vague response. Since it was a direction to look into not a complete answer, MrD  correctly added a comment, not an answer

Comment: @Geoff, I did not want anybody to do research for me. I asked the question if there is a ready solution or if somebody else thought the same thing and did something about this. Before asking the question I searched of course. And, yes I know it can be done with jQuery but only knowing that is not enough to be able to do it easily. Thanks.

Comment: I hope my solution works for you , but there might be an issue , if user enters less than 20 characters , and submitt the form , he/she will face an error cause he/she hasn't fill some required fields

Comment: I think you need to disable the required field or it won't work with JS if someone's comments is less than 20 characters. drupal_add_js in a form_alter + change form required array to null.

Comment: @Namari, I think adding another condition (don't submit the comment if it is less than 20 characters) will solve the problem you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: why don't you want to show the mandatory field? They are mandatory so even if you don't display them, they will fail at the form validation.

Comment: Actually I want not to show them at first. If anybody enter something to comment text area (or touch), then other fields are displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Paste in file `template.php`

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'comment_node_blog_form') {
    $form['author']['name']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'validate[required]';
    $form['author']['mail']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'validate[required,custom[email]]';
    $form['comment_body']['und'][0]['#attributes']['class'][] = 'validate[required,minSize[20]]';
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js';
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/js/jquery.validationEngine.js';
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/js/scripts.js';
  }
}
```

#### change `form_id` with your form comment

[image]

#### Source [jQuery validate](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) and file scripts.js

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#comment-form").validationEngine();
        $('#comment-form').find('.form-type-textfield').hide();
        $('#edit-comment-body').keyup(function() {
            var value = $(this).find('.text-full').val(),
                lenght = value.length;
            if (lenght > 20) {
                $('#comment-form').find('.form-type-textfield').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#comment-form').find('.form-type-textfield').hide();
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

#### Form with empty text

[image: form with empty text]

#### Form with more 20 characters

[image: Form with more 20 characters]

Comment: Your answer looks perfect for the case and it **also** gave me some other ideas to use in forms. Thanks, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you clarify your question at first, I may have solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an js file to hide and show elements , if you dont know how to write that code , read [Jquery text change event](https://api.jquery.com/change/) , [jquery hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [jquery show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) . now in your module file Implement form-alter for comment form , and add your js file to form using :

```
 function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == *****){//find comment form id using firebug
    $form['#attached']['js'][] = array(
      'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MODULE_NAME').'/js/myscript.js', 
      'type' => 'file',
    );
  }
}
```

if you don't know how to find comment form_id look here : http://www.digett.com/blog/05/26/2011/how-theme-comment-form-drupal-7

Answer (score 1):

To do so you can use [Field Conditional States](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_conditional_state) or [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) modules.

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the right condition.
>   When editing a node (or any other entity type that supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are dynamically modified with the States API.
>   You can, for example, define a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser" checkbox is checked

These dependencies are not only between the fields of the content type but also between the fields of the comment fields as well. As an example

[image]

These modules allows you set dependencies among the fields of comments as well, As you can see *Comment Dependencies* is for doing such thing:

[image]

You can also use [Field formatter conditions](https://www.drupal.org/project/ffc) module. This module changes the format of fields in *manage display* base on conditions of other fields.

> Adds conditions to field formatters. Configuration happens on the "Manage Display" screens of every entity type on a per field basis when clicking on the cogwheel on the right.

So by this module you can

- Hide source field when target field is empty.
- Hide source field when target field is not empty.
- Hide source field when current user has specific roles.
- Hide source field on specific pages.
- Hide source field when target field contains a specific string.
- Hide source field when target field doesn't contain a specific string.
- Hide link field if title is empty.
- Hide date field if from/to has expired.